# Setting default ResourceBundle .properties file

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Normally a ResourceBundle .properties file without any locale at the end is treated as default.

I want my application to load `*_en_US.properties` files by default because I don't want to include .properties files without locale (like `example.properties`).

Is there any way to globally set it this way (preferably in some kind of .properties or .xml file)?

Comment: You simply have to make sure that your application locale is always set (using a default value that should be set at appropriate time).
What kind of architecture do you have: webapp? spring? other?

Comment: If the default locale is en_US, you won't have anything to do (assuming you use ResourceBundle.getBundle()): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29

Comment: My app is an Internet website and I'll have to grab locale from user's browser. The thing is - I want my app to use en_US when user has a locale that is not recognized. In this situation it searches for a file without locale extension which obviously is not there.